# How do I make my server-sider rendered Angular application not “flicker” when it transitions to the javascript application?

Tags: seo, single-page-application, angular.js

For our business, SEO is exceptionally important, so though we have an Angular 7 app, we use server-side rendering so that Google et al. can easily access our content. (I know they supposedly render SPAs like Angular apps, but we've found they still strongly prefer server-side rendered content and are much better at scraping it.)

The problem is that the server-side rendered version of a page is oftentimes subtly different from the version when the javascript application fully boots up. For example, the top of the page can be different if you're authenticated. I also think that the fonts are slightly different.

The result is that the user sees the server-side rendered version first, and then the javascript application "flashes" into place. It's ugly:

[image: Flickering while loading]

I would much rather the flow be:

- If the user does not have javascript enabled (i.e., is a webscraper like Google) they correctly get the server-side rendered version.
- If the user has javascript enabled, they see a loading screen (for example, empty content, like Facebook while loading) or even just a spinner, and then the app fades into view.

Is there an intelligent way to do this? A design hack, correct use of the noscript tag, or something else?